# Regex to extract all repeating characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that extracts all repeating characters in a string. They do not need to be consecutive. So for the string `abacb` I want to extract `[a, b]`.

Unfortunately, I can only come up with methods that give me just `a`. Like:

```
    /(\w).+?(?:\1)/.exec('abacb');
    // Array [ "aba", "a" ]
```

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short solution using [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function with specific regex pattern:

```js
var str = 'abacb',
    result = str.match(/(\w)(?=.*?\1)/g);

console.log(result);
```

`(\w)` - first capturing group containing a repeated character

`\1` - backreference to the first capturing group(means that some character is repeated)

---

To get only unique matched characters use `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()` functions:

```js
var str = 'aaaaabcbaa',
    result = str.match(/(\w)(?=.*?\1)/gm);

if (result) {
    result = result.filter(function(c, i, a) { return i === a.lastIndexOf(c); })
}
console.log(result);
```

Or ***Ecmascript6*** approach using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object and *[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)*:

```js
var str = 'aaaaabcbaa',
    result = str.match(/(\w)(?=.*?\1)/gm);

if (result) {
    result = [...new Set(result)];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `.match(/(\w)(?=.*?\1)/g)` won't work well with `'aba\ncb\n'` string.

Comment: Nice! Only `str = 'aaa'` returns `[a, a]`. But I could check the result array for duplicates as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, not quite sure. In this case , all whitespaces should be considered `\r\t\n\....`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to convert string to array and then apply filter

```js
var str='cabccb';
var arr=str.split('');
var duplicate_entry = arr.reduce(function(acc, el, i, arr1) {
  if (arr1.indexOf(el) !== i && acc.indexOf(el) < 0) acc.push(el); return acc;
}, []);
console.log(duplicate_entry);
```

Comment: I have to say I really like this solution as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the characters in an object and even count how many times each character occured.

```js
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...";

var chars = {};

string.split("").forEach(function(chr) {
  if (chars.hasOwnProperty(chr)) {
    chars[chr]++;
  } else {
    chars[chr] = 1;
  }
});

console.log(Object.keys(chars));
console.log(chars);
```